# Differenza tra "riva" e "sponda"

Tags: word-usage, difference, vocabulary, synonym

Voglio poter spiegare la differenza tra **riva** e **sponda**, che in tedesco dovrebbe essere sempre *Ufer*. Intuisco quale sia la differenza ma vorrei sentire se secondo voi ho ragione o se mi sfugge qualcosa.

"Riva" e "sponda" in italiano in questi casi sono sinonimi:

1. "la sponda/riva di un lago o fiume". Non so se si possa dire se si tratta di mare.
2. "in riva al mare".

Sbaglio?

Comment: Foscolo usa “sponde” per indicare dove il mare Ionio lambisce l'isola di Zacinto.

Comment: Treccani usa "sponda" anche per il mare: "Tratto di terreno che delimita una distesa o un corso d’acqua (sinonimo più elevato di riva): **la sponda del mare**; le sponde del lago, di un fiume, di un canale."

Comment: Sponda mi da più l’idea di qualcosa che limita e contiene, per cui più adatto al corso di un fiume o il perimetro di un lago. Mentre riva da più l’idea di uno  spazio aperto,  più tipico del mare. Entrambi i termini sono comunque spesso usati come sinonimi. Nota ad esempio il modo di dire “fare da sponda”.

Answer (score 1):

La sponda è solo il confine tra acqua e terraferma. La riva, invece, è la terraferma accanto a dell'acqua (fiume, lago, mare, ecc...).

Quindi, sì, si può dire 'la sponda del mare'.

Comment: Non ho dato il voto negativo, ma i commenti alla risposta dicono che “sponda” si usa anche per il mare.

Comment: @egreg grazie per avermelo fatto notare! correggo subito! (PS il voto negativo è stato praticamente sicuramente causato da come io, per sbaglio, in 'lago' ho scrittto k al posto di l. Infatti, c'è anche una proposta di cancellare il post...)

Comment: Perché solo “accanto a un fiume”? Il Treccani definisce “riva” come “La zona di terra che delimita una distesa d’acque (mare, lago) o un corso d’acqua”.

Comment: @DaG grazie! Intendevo acqua, correggo subito!